# Is there any AIX/Win equivalent command to Solaris pmap?

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, aix, solaris-10

I am working on memory management in different OS like AIX, Win and Unix. The pmap command works fine for Solaris but I can't able to find the similar command for AIX.

Is pmap works in AIX or is there any similar command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For AIX this will be [procmap](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/procmap.htm) which, according to documentation "prints the address space map of processes".

You can also have a look at [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) which is a Python

> module providing an interface for retrieving information on all running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory, disks, network, users) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many functionalities offered by command line tools such as: ps, top, ..., pmap. [...] It currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX and FreeBSD.

Comment: Does pmap supports all flavors of UNIX (Solaris, linux, etc ) ?